# Rank of matrix after cropping

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Consider a nonnegative operator $T$ (as in all its eigenvalues are nonnegative) on a $d$-dimensional Hilbert space with rank $r < d$ so that its nullity is $n = d - r$. Let us use a standard basis $e_1, \dots, e_d$ so that $T_{ij}$ denotes its matrix representation. Suppose that we crop the matrix $T$ to form a new matrix $T_k$, in the following way, i.e., $T_k$ is a $(n+k)$-square matrix with entries $T_{ij}$ for $1 \le i,j \le n+k$.

Suppose that the projection operator onto $\ker T$ is [irreducible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem#Classification_of_matrices) as a matrix operator with respect to the standard basis. Is it true that

$$ \ker T_k=n, \quad\forall k \le n $$

**Some background.** This claim seems to be used in this paper (Mielke, Andreas. [Ferromagnetism in the Hubbard model and Hund's rule](https://doi.org/10.1016/0375-9601(93)90207-G). Physics Letters A 174, no. 5-6 (1993): 443-448.) (see Eq. 16), but since it's a mathematical physics paper, I attempted to omit all the unnecessary stuff in my question.

Comment: What do you mean by a "non-negative" operator? Do you mean that it is [positive semidefinite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix) or that its matrix has non-negative entries? What do you mean by "irreducible"? Is the definition [given here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem#Classification_of_matrices) equivalent to yours? It is unusual to talk about irreducibility outside of the context of matrices with non-negative entries; do we have a reason to believe that the matrix of the proejction operator has non-negative entries?

Comment: Please let me know if I'm misinterpreting the question, but I don't think this is true. Consider the $d$ by $d$ matrix with ones for all of its entries. It has a nullspace of dimension $n=(d-1)$. Consider the case of $k=0$, which has $k<n$. The resulting matrix $T_k$ has a nullspace of only dimension $d-2$, which is smaller than $n$. I haven't checked irreducibility of the projector, is that easy to see? Or is $k=0$ a sort of edge/trivial case not being considered?